# How Do You Prove That This Puzzle Is Physically Solvable?

Tags: geometry

https://www.reddit.com/r/BeAmazed/comments/fyt7x9/it_seems_to_be_impossible_but_it_gets_done/?ref=share&ref_source=link

The goal of the puzzle is to remove the wooden stick from the jar by fiddling with it.

Is it possible to mathematically/physically prove that the puzzle is solvable, given the precise dimensions of all the components?

I've seen mathematical articles about moving couches around cornered hallways, so I figured the question is suited here.

Comment: I think the video is proof enough. Some very fine plier-tool might also come in handy